# Padding in div container HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, padding

I´m trying to make the image below to fit the whole div, meaning that the background image should take the whole space and I shouldn't see the green color. Unfortunately I can´t find a way to do it.

```css
#imagecontainer {
  background: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg") no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container no-padding" id="maincontent" tabindex="-1">
  <div id="imagecontainer" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/profile.png" alt="">
      <div class="intro-text">
        <h1 class="name">Start Bootstrap</h1>
        <h1 class="name">Start Bootstrap</h1>
        <h1 class="name">Start Bootstrap</h1>
        <hr class="star-light">
        <span class="skills">Web Developer - Graphic Artist - User Experience Designer</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: is `width` and `height` 100%?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, where do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your using `container`, use `container-fluid` to make it full width. Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/Mmrmzz)

Comment: thanks for the answer but with container-fluid the image is cut and I want it to be full visible

Comment: @AlbertoCarmona  I have updated my answer. You were missing height on body and i think background properties weren't in right order.

Comment: that´s great for the width many thanks but, what happens with the height? in your example the image is cut even if I add more text. Is there any solutions to this? thanks again!

Comment: I found the solution! Just changing height:100% to height:250% and it works! Many thanks @Nofel

Answer (score -1):

The *#maincontent* div has a padding, a positive margin and a width set in pixels; and the *#imagecontainer* has a negative margin.

This is because that's the way Bootstrap deals to accomodate items in its grid.

You could considerate using a fluid Jumbotron instead to use the full width and take the necessary vertical space for your content.

This could be of help: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/jumbotron/